# How to sanely debug Next.js build TypeErrors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Is it possible to extend Javascript's built-in `TypeError` so in addition to the usual:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slug')
> at FormCheckout (/opt/app/.next/server/pages/[language]/[template]/checkout.js:185:28)

it would also display the actual broken code in the message console?

---

My specific use-case is running the `next build` (of Next.js), and the current state of the error is not helpful at all. See:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slug')
    at FormCheckout (/opt/app/.next/server/pages/[language]/[template]/checkout.js:185:28)
    at Wc (/opt/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/opt/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/opt/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/opt/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/opt/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/opt/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at Zc (/opt/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
    at Z (/opt/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/opt/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
```

You can only imagine how many actual `.slug` code is there (167 - I checked). The stacktrace shows a single `FormCheckout` component file in the `.next/server/pages/` directory, and files in there are not readable.

**To be perfectly clear:** I do know the **reason** of `TypeError` occurrence - I only want to know **how to debug it easier**.